# create three elements in adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have already make navigation drawer with a ImageView and a TextView,and it can run.However, when I want to creat navigation drawer with two ImageViews and a TextView ,it will show the error("Attempt to invoke virtual method") with my second ImageView(the variable's name  in my code is "img")

My code like this:

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//...

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    
    TextView Title = null;
    ImageView Icon = null;
    ImageView img = null;

    if (v == null) {
        
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
        Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
        Icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
        img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

    }

    Title.setText(mTitle[position]);
    
    Icon.setImageResource(mIcon[position]);
    img.setImageResource(mimg[position]);

    return v;
}
```

this is my logcat:

> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at com.test.adapter.MenuListAdapter.getView(MenuListAdapter.java:84)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:914)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2076)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1833)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1058)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
> 09-16 22:25:38.458: E/AndroidRuntime(14966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)

Answer (score 0):

you assigned the inflated view to `v`, but you are using `convertView` to look for the inflated views widget. Get rid of v and use just convertView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer, parent, false);
    }

    // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

    title.setText(mTitle[position]);
    icon.setImageResource(mIcon[position]);
    img.setImageResource(mimg[position]);

   return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I  tried your advice, but it's show a same error

Comment: I don't know how to post my xml here, so I add an answer

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    <ImageView
>        android:id="@+id/icon"
>        android:layout_width="30dp"
>        android:layout_height="30dp"
>        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
>        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
>        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
>        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
>
>
>
>    <TextView
>        android:id="@+id/title"
>        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>        android:textColor="#848484"
>        android:textSize="15dp" />
>
>    <TextView
>        android:id="@+id/textABC"
>        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>        android:text="TextView" />
> ```